# My Rails Aplication start to raise ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation in some random queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

since yesterday, my production app starts to raise `ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation` in some queries of my entire application!

I can't imagine how to gives an exact context of every error since this error occurs on random places of my application! I can't simulate this errors calling the same block of code in Rails Console, only in the controllers in production environment.

We don't change any query, I become to think this can be a bug or some change in the database configuration(?).
Did someone already get this errors? Any idea what I can search for?

Backtrace (of one error):

```
ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation: ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation
  from active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:923:in `assert_mutability!'
  from active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:915:in `set_value'
  from active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:74:in `references_values='
  from active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:176:in `references!'
  from active_record/relation/merger.rb:76:in `block in merge'
  from active_record/relation/merger.rb:66:in `each'
  from active_record/relation/merger.rb:66:in `merge'
  from active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb:45:in `merge!'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:49:in `public_send'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:49:in `block in method_missing'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:345:in `using_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:85:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:329:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:84:in `run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/shard_tracking.rb:31:in `run_on_shard'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:45:in `method_missing'
  from active_record/associations/association.rb:79:in `scope'
  from active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:288:in `scope'
  from active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:960:in `scope'
  from active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:1130:in `order'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:49:in `public_send'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:49:in `block in method_missing'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:345:in `using_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:85:in `block in run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:329:in `keeping_connection_proxy'
  from octopus/proxy.rb:84:in `run_queries_on_shard'
  from octopus/shard_tracking.rb:31:in `run_on_shard'
  from octopus/relation_proxy.rb:45:in `method_missing'
  from app/controllers/v2/app/details_controller.rb:9:in `show'
  from action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
  from abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
  from scout_apm/instruments/action_controller_rails_3_rails4.rb:72:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  from abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from raven/integrations/rails/controller_transaction.rb:7:in `block in included'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
  from abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  from active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  from action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
  from active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
  from scout_apm/instruments/action_controller_rails_3_rails4.rb:94:in `process_action'
  from abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
  from action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
  from action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
  from scout_apm/instruments/rails_router.rb:29:in `call_with_scout_instruments'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/context_collect.rb:18:in `call'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/localization.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in call'
  from active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/localization.rb:39:in `in_timezone'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/localization.rb:28:in `block in call'
  from i18n.rb:297:in `with_locale'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/localization.rb:43:in `with_locale'
  from rails_api_utils/middleware/localization.rb:27:in `call'
  from rack/request_id.rb:30:in `block in call'
  from request_id.rb:60:in `with'
  from rack/request_id.rb:29:in `call'
  from scout_apm/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  from request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  from rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  from rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  from rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
  from enterprise/trace_id/middlewares/rack_middleware.rb:21:in `block in call'
  from enterprise/trace_id/tracer/tracer.rb:13:in `block in trace'
  from <internal:prelude>:137:in `__enable'
  from <internal:prelude>:137:in `enable'
  from enterprise/trace_id/tracer/tracer.rb:13:in `trace'
  from enterprise/trace_id/middlewares/rack_middleware.rb:21:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
  from request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
  from rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  from active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  from rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  from raven/integrations/rack.rb:51:in `call'
  from scout_apm/instruments/middleware_summary.rb:58:in `call'
  from rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
  from puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  from puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
  from puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
  from puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
  from puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Details controller code (I've omitted some enterprises model names):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class DetailsController < V2::ApplicationController
  def show
    model = Model.find(params[:pricing_id])
    details = model.details.order(:position)
    details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }
    Detail.cascade_formula_arguments(details, params)
    details = details.select(&:available?)

    render json: details, each_serializer: ::V2::DetailSerializer
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post full backtrace errors? But also did you look here? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ImmutableRelation.html

Comment: see `app/controllers/v2/app/details_controller.rb:9:in `show'` can you post this controller method?

Comment: I've already check this link, my application doesn't make this kind of method call, I think It's can be some private call of Rails

Comment: Backtrace and controller added!

Comment: it looks like `details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }` is modifying data right?

Comment: what does `Detail.cascade_formula_arguments` do?

Comment: What is this `details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }`? `details` is already related to `model` since it was loaded via `model.details` so reassociating it to the same `model` seems like a huge waste and using `each` will cause `details` to load and then you are trying to mutate that relationship by reassigning it to the same relationship which may be the issue here.

Comment: I use `dentaku` gem to implement the `cascade_formula_arguments`

Comment: I start to investigate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you wish to modify the data I would suggest mapping this to an array of hashes... but not sure what `Detail.cascade_formula_arguments(details, params)` is doing so this is a guess.

I would try to convert the data to hash instead of active record object unless you really are trying to modify them so something like this:

```
details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }
details = details.map(&:as_json)
```

#### Updated

Based on comments by @engineersmnky, and my own thought that this line of code is likely where your problem is, can you just remove this line of code?  What is its purpose? See if you can remove it.

```
# try to remove this from your code
details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }
```

Comment: This `details.each { |detail| detail.model = model }` seems  superfluous and highly problematic. `details` is already associated to the `model` given the fact that it was obtained via `model.details`. The call to `each` then requires `details` to actually load the `Detail` data at which point it is being modified to reflect the same association. I think this may be the issue because it is loaded via an association that knows `model` and `details` and then reassignment of this relationship is occurring. While the assignment is identical I am not certain `rails` cares about this trivial detail

Comment: @engineersmnky, I also think that line is the problem. But are you suggesting an improvement to this answer?

Comment: I guess. If you also think that that is the issue why include that same code in your answer? Wouldn't this just raise the same error?